# How to place all floats currently in holding queue at specific point

Tags: floats, positioning

I read a great post by [Frank Mittelbach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) on how floats work, but I still have a problem: Is there a way to empty the float holding queue, thus placing all figures/tables ect at a certain point. Namely I would like a function that works as follows:

```
\section{1} 
figure 1
figure 2
\emptyFloatQueue
\section{2}
figure 3
table 1
\emptyFloatQueue
\section{3}
...
```

The \emptyFloatQueue function should ensure that all floats are typeset before any subsequent lines. Thus figure 1 and figure 2 MUST appear before section 2 and figure 3 and table 1 MUST appear before section 3 etc. It doesn't matter where the floats are placed, as long as they are placed before their respective subsequent sections.

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT:**

- If there are no floats in the queue I don't want behavior to change.
- I would like the floats to be placed as normally as possible (not separately on a float page, but inline along with the text)

Comment: `\clearpage` ?? (As that answer says.)

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the page break? If there are no floats in the queue I dont want the behavior to change. And I don't want the floats to appear on their own float pages, I would like them to be typeset as normal (in top or bottom area with the text)

Comment: \afterpage{\clearpage} waits until the top of a new page to execute.  That is about as normal as it gets.

Comment: You can't avoid them going to float pages. If there are floats in the queue, it is because LaTeX has not been able to place them in preferred locations. Without a minimal example, it is hard to say. But unless you are overriding the defaults, you have a limited set of options: relax the restrictions on placing the floats at the top or bottom (either globally or for specific floats) or allow them to be placed on float pages. I don't see that there are any other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\FloatBar­rier` command from the [placeins](http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package seems to do the trick.

The documentation states;

> `Placeins.sty` keeps floats ‘in their place’, preventing them from floating past a `\FloatBarrier` command into another section. To use it, declare
>   `\usepackage{placeins}` and insert `\FloatBarrier` at places that floats
>   should not move past, perhaps at every `\section`